# Add account activation url from Microsoft Identity to SendGrid email dynamic templates - ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I created an Asp.net project and added Identity. I want to use SendGrid dynamic email templates (not the LegacyTemplates) for account confirmation. Basically, **I want to insert the tokens generated by the microsoft idendity on a button in the SendGrid template**. How can I do that?

Here's my code:

```
public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
        {
            Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
        }

        public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; }

        public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
        {
            return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
        }

        public Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)
        {
            apiKey = "api key";
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress("my email", Options.SendGridUser),
                Subject = subject,
                PlainTextContent = message,
                HtmlContent = message,
            };

            SetTemplateId("Template Code");
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));
            msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);

            return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
```

The template:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SubstitutionTags](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/substitution-tags).

This is how I have done this:

I have created an `EmailBase` class:

```
public abstract class EmailBase 
{
    public EmailBase()
    {
        ToDisplayName = string.Empty;
        ToFullName = string.Empty;
        FromDisplayName = string.Empty;
        FromFullName = string.Empty;
        Subject = string.Empty;
        Content = string.Empty;
        HtmlContent = string.Empty;
        TemplateId = string.Empty;
    }

    // note that I am using a default Sender email, you can modify this...
    public EmailBase(string toFirstName, string toLastName, string toEmail)
    {
        ToDisplayName = toFirstName;
        ToFullName = toFirstName + " " + toLastName;
        ToEmail = toEmail;
        FromDisplayName = string.Empty;
        FromEmail = "mailer@my-domain.com"; // I am using a default sender email
        FromFullName = "my-domain support"; // Whatever name you want for this email
        ReplyToEmail = string.Empty;
        ReplyToFullName = string.Empty;
        Subject = string.Empty;
        Content = string.Empty;
        HtmlContent = string.Empty;
        TemplateId = string.Empty;
        Attachment = null;
        AttachmentFileName = string.Empty;
    }

    public string ToDisplayName { get; set; }

    public string ToEmail { get; set; }

    public string ToFullName { get; set; }

    public string FromDisplayName { get; set; }

    public string FromEmail { get; set; }

    public string FromFullName { get; set; }

    public string ReplyToEmail { get; set; }

    public string ReplyToFullName { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public string HtmlContent { get; set; }

    public string TemplateId { get; set; }

    public byte[] Attachment { get; set; }

    public string AttachmentFileName { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> SubstitutionTags { get; set; }
}
```

Now for each one of your Templates, you can create a corresponding class which inherits from `EmailBase`, for example you can create `EmailAddressConfirmationEmail` for this template:

```
public class EmailAddressConfirmationEmail : EmailBase
{
    public EmailAddressConfirmationEmail(string toFirstName, string toLastName, string toEmail, string embededUrl)
            : base(toFirstName, toLastName, toEmail)
    {
        // by default from is set to mailer@my-domain.com

        TemplateId = "your-template-id";

        SubstitutionTags = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "-name-", ToDisplayName },
            { "-confirmationurl-", embededUrl }
        };
    }
}
```

Finally this is how you can create an email service to generate your `SendGridMessage`:

```
public class SendGridEmailService
{
    private readonly string _apiKey;

    public SendGridEmailService(string apiKey)
    {
        _apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    public int SendEmail(EmailBase email)
    {
        var client = new SendGridClient(_apiKey);
        Task<int> task = Task.Run<int>(async () => await SendEmailAsync(email));
        return task.Result;
    }

    public async Task<int> SendEmailAsync(EmailBase email)
    {
        var client = new SendGridClient(_apiKey);
        var sendGridMessage = BuildSendGridMessage(email);
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(sendGridMessage);

        return (int)response.StatusCode;
    }

    /*
     * This is the important function which builds SendGridMessage, 
     * Note how we are using SubstitutionTags to achieve what you want
     */
    private SendGridMessage BuildSendGridMessage(EmailBase email)
    {
        SendGridMessage sendGridMessage = new SendGridMessage
        {
            From = new EmailAddress(email.FromEmail, email.FromFullName)
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.ReplyToEmail))
        {
            sendGridMessage.ReplyTo = new EmailAddress(email.ReplyToEmail, email.ReplyToFullName);
        }

        sendGridMessage.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email.ToEmail, email.ToFullName));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.TemplateId))
        {
            sendGridMessage.SetTemplateId(email.TemplateId);
            sendGridMessage.Personalizations[0].Substitutions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> p in email.SubstitutionTags)
            {
                sendGridMessage.Personalizations[0].Substitutions.Add(p.Key, p.Value);
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.Subject))
        {
            sendGridMessage.Subject = email.Subject;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.Content))
        {
            sendGridMessage.AddContent("text/plain", email.Content);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.HtmlContent))
        {
            sendGridMessage.HtmlContent = email.HtmlContent;
        }

        if (email.Attachment != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.AttachmentFileName))
        {
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                var base4File = Convert.ToBase64String(email.Attachment);
                sendGridMessage.AddAttachment(email.AttachmentFileName, base4File);
            }
        }

        return sendGridMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okokok but my problem is that I have this class made by Ms Identity: https://pastebin.com/C96kZtQ4 and other classes also made by MS identity  like this one for example: https://pastebin.com/EiPRhFrf How to I combine your answer with these pages...Or I dont need them anymore?!

Comment: I tried to find an example of SendGrid templates used for the account confirmation email...but I didn't find...and I can't figure it out how to mix them..

Comment: Where should I call RegisterConfirmationEmail email template?

Comment: You would need modify or extend those classes and include a **Key Value Pair**  for substitution tags... Then set the SubstitutionTags in your `SendGridMessage` as shown in this line: `sendGridMessage.Personalizations[0].Substitutions.Add(p.Key, p.Value);`... then SendGrid will replace `SubstitutionTags` in your template.

Comment: Where should I instalntiatethe different email templates? And is there any other changes beside adding that key value pair in those classes?  Sorry to bother your but I couldn't find any working exam online :(

Comment: No worries... In the code that you have posted, you have this method: `Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)`... you would need to add an extra parameter to this method for SubstitutionTags... for example, your method becomes like this: `Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email, Dictionary<string, string> SubstitutionTags substitutionTags)`

Comment: It's just a lot cleaner to put all those parameters in one `class` and pass that type as a parameter instead of pass so many parameters...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235042/discussion-between-andreea-purta-and-hooman-bahreini).